# Consuming an IAsyncEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iasyncenumerable

I have one web API application that has a function that needs to stream some data. Then I have another web application that basically acts like a proxy for that. This other application does a whole lot of other stuff like handling authorization and such. It needs to connect to the API endpoint and pass the stream through potentially doing some addition processing for each row of data. In one case it will need to write out that data into an Excel file, for example.

Unfortunately, I see a lot of tutorials on how to create an IAsyncEnumerable, but not any about actually connecting to an endpoint that exposes one.

Ideally, I would like to actually wrap my IAsyncEnumerable and return it with some other *stuff*. This is what I basically do with other non-streamed endpoints already:

```
public class NonStreamedResult : BaseResult
{
    public SomeMetaData MetaData {get; set; }
    // here Data is usually small, so returning it all at once is no big deal
    public IEnumerable<SomeData> Data {get; set; }  
}

//....controller
public async Task<NonStreamedResult> GetNonStreamedData()
```

And on the consuming side, I'm using an `HttpClient`, awaiting an `HttpResponseMessage` and using `ReadAsAsync<T>` to turn that response into an object.

However, if I try to do this:

```
public class StreamedResult : BaseResult
{
    public SomeOtherMetaData MetaData {get; set; }
    // Here data could be huge, so we don't want to have to hold it all in memory at once
    public IAsyncEnumerable<SomeData> Data {get; set; }
}

//....controller
public async Task<StreamedResult> GetStreamedData()
```

I will get an error when it tries to deserialize because it doesn't know what concrete class to convert the `IAsyncEnumerable` into.

So what's the right way to connect to an endpoint that is using an `IAsyncEnumerable` *without* loading the entire response into memory (obviously) so that I can eventually return another `IAsyncEnumerable` from the proxy app?

It would be nice if I could still pass it wrapped, but it's not the end of the world if I have to work with just the naked `IAsyncEnumerable`

Note that I'm using the `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` NuGet package since I'm still targeting an earlier version of the .NET framework.

Comment: When receiving data the code must know where the end of the data occurs. You can't keep on appending data to the end of the transmission without some delimiter when sending multiple objects.  Than on receive end you have to be able to split the data around the delimiters.  Also you may not receive one object on each read so code has to be able to take pieces of Async receive data an append into larger objects until the delimiter is found.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm still targeting an earlier version of the .NET framework.

That's not going to work well. [Unbuffered `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` support was added in ASP.NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/iasyncenumerable-not-buffered-by-mvc).

If you can't upgrade, then you'll need to write your own streaming JSON parser and your own streaming JSON serializer wrapped up in a custom formatter that flushes periodically. This is a non-trivial amount of work. The remainder of my answer assumes you will move to .NET 6.

> It would be nice if I could still pass it wrapped, but it's not the end of the world if I have to work with just the naked IAsyncEnumerable

Wrapped can't possibly work. Just consider the situation where you define multiple `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` properties. When dealing with `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` in ASP.NET 6, you must return it as a top-level type. Metadata can be represented as headers.

To consume, first ensure that you set the `HttpClient` completion options so that the HTTP operation is considered "complete" when the headers are received, and then you can take the response body stream and pass it to [`JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasyncenumerable?view=net-6.0). After retrieving each item from the downstream API, you can do whatever processing you need and then `yield` it to be streamed to your client.